# Google Map API v3 InfoWindow won't open with setContent from a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a simple Google map v3 code.  It creates the map and adds a marker to the markerCluster.  It is all working fine, except for setting content to the infoWindow and opening it.
The function `getSupplierDetails()` simply returns a short string (i.e. "Red Supply").

Here is the problem:  If I hard code the text "Red Supply" to the setContent line like `infoWindow.setContent("Red Supply");` then the infowindow open fine with the content.

But if I leave it as it is as in the code below the infowindow does not open at all, although the `getSupplierDetails()` function returns "Red Supply".

`getSupplierDetails()` function returns this JSON string:  `{"popupContent": "Red Suppplier"}` from Firebug.

Spent so long on it without any solution.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
var map;
var markerCluster;
var infoWindow;

$(document).ready(function() {

  if (mapElem != null) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.664936, -2.706299);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, myOptions);
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    AddMarkers();
  }
});

function AddMarkers(){
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    var marker = new google.maps.marker({position:latLng, map:map, title:"title"});

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      var res = getSupplierDetails();
      infoWindow.setContent(res);
      infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
}


function getSupplierDetails() { //returns {"popupContent": "Red Suppplier"}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sitedetail.aspx",
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data) {
            return data.popupContent;
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(resp.message);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is `getSupplierDetails()`? Without that, we have no idea what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Added the getSupplierDetails() to the questions.  But it is just returning a string.

Comment: Add `return` on the first line of `getSupplierDetails()` before `$.ajax({`

Comment: Added the `return`.  This calls the function as before, but returns a XMLHttpRequest object to the part where I'm assigning the content. I'm struggling to extract the data from this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSupplierDetails() { // returns "Red Suppplier" or ""
    var content = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sitedetail.aspx",
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data) {
            content = data.popupContent;
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(resp.message);

        }
    });
    return content;
}
```

Comment: For some reason the value that is returned is blank.  Checking the readyState returns 1, sugesting it is still loading while the value is returned (?).  Anyway I have moved the `setContent` line inside the success part of the AJAX call.  This seems to be working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax success call is asynchronous that's why you are getting null, What you did is fine (moving the SetContent to de success part) but you could also do this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  getSupplierDetails(function(res){
     infoWindow.setContent(res)
  });
  infoWindow.setContent(res);
  infoWindow.open(map, this);
});

function getSupplierDetails(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sitedetail.aspx",
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data.popupContent);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(resp.message);

        }
    });
}
```